# How to use seaborn for a time series boxplot with nested data?

Tags: python, seaborn, boxplot, categorical-data

### Situation

I’m trying to create a boxplot with individual and nested/grouped data. The dataset I use represents information for a number of households, where there is a distinction between 1-phase and 3-phase systems **(#)**

[image: Snippet from the exported csv]

> **#NOTE** Where the id appears only once, the household is single phased (1-phase) and duplicates are 3-phase system. Due to the duplicates, reading the csv-file via `pd.read_csv(..)` will extend the duplicate's names (i.e. `1`, `1.1` and `1.2`).

Using the basic plot techniques delivers:

```
In [4]: VoltageProfileFile= pd.read_csv(dest + '/VoltageProfiles_' + str(PV_par['value_PV']) + '%PV.csv', dtype= 'float')
   ...: VoltageProfileFile.boxplot(figsize=(20,5), rot= 60)
   ...: plt.ylim(0.9, 1.1)
   ...: plt.show()

Out[4]:
```

[image: Boxplot year simulation]

The result is correct, but it would be clean to have only 1 tick representing 1, 1.1 and 1.2 or 5, 5.1, 5.2 etc.

### Question

I would like to clean this up by using a ‘categorical’ boxplot, where values from duplicates (3-phase systems) are grouped under the same id. I’m aware that seaborn enables users to use the hue parameter: `sns.boxplot(x='',hue='', y='', data='')` to create categorical plots ([Plotting with categorical data](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/categorical.html)). However, I can’t figure out how to format my dataset in order to achieve this? I tried via `pd.melt(..)` function (cfr. [pandas.melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html)), but the resulting format changes the order in which the values appear (*)

> (*) *Every id is accompanied by a length up to a reference point, thus the order of appearance on the x-axis must remain.*

What would be a good approach to tackle this problem?
Ideally, the boxplot would group 3-phase systems under one id and display different colours for 1ph vs. 3ph systems.

Kind regards,

Rémy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For seaborn plotting, data should be structured in long format and not wide format as you have it with distinct indicators such as *household*, *phase*, *value*.

So consider actually letting Pandas rename columns 1, 1.1, 1.2 and then run `pd.melt` into long format with adjustments of the generated `household` and `phase` columns using `assign` where you split on `.` and take the first and second parts respectively:

```
VoltageProfileFile_long = (pd.melt(VoltageProfileFile, var_name = 'phase')
                             .assign(household = lambda x: x['phase'].str.split("\\.").str[0].astype(int),
                                     phase = lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x['phase'].str.split("\\.").str[1]).fillna(0).astype(int).add(1))
                             .reindex(['household', 'phase', 'value'], axis='columns')
                          )
```

---

Below is a demo with random data

**Data** *(dumped to csv then read back in for pandas renaming process)*

```
np.random.seed(111620)

VoltageProfileFile = pd.DataFrame([np.random.uniform(0.95, 1.05, 13) for i in range(50)], 
                                  columns = [1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
VoltageProfileFile.to_csv('data.csv', index=False)

VoltageProfileFile = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
VoltageProfileFile.head(10)
#           1       1.1       1.2         2         3  ...       5.2         6         7         8         9
# 0  1.012732  1.042768  0.975577  0.965508  1.048544  ...  1.010898  1.008921  1.006769  1.019615  1.036926
# 1  1.013457  1.048378  1.025201  0.982988  0.995133  ...  1.024578  1.024362  0.985693  1.041609  0.995037
# 2  1.024739  1.008590  0.960278  0.956811  1.001739  ...  0.969436  0.953134  0.966851  1.031544  1.036572
# 3  1.037998  0.993246  0.970146  0.989196  0.959527  ...  1.015577  1.027020  1.038941  0.971666  1.040658
# 4  0.995877  0.955734  0.952497  1.040942  0.985759  ...  1.021805  1.044108  0.980657  1.034179  0.980722
# 5  0.994755  0.951557  0.986580  1.021583  0.959249  ...  1.046740  0.998429  1.027406  1.007391  0.989477
# 6  1.023979  1.043418  1.020745  1.006081  1.030413  ...  0.964579  1.035479  0.982969  0.953484  1.005889
# 7  1.018904  1.045440  1.003997  1.018295  0.954814  ...  0.955295  0.960958  0.999492  1.010163  0.985847
# 8  0.960913  0.982671  1.016659  1.030384  1.043750  ...  1.042720  0.972287  1.039235  0.969571  0.999418
# 9  1.017085  0.998049  0.989664  0.953420  1.018018  ...  0.953041  0.955883  1.004630  0.996443  1.017762
```

**Plot** *(after same processing to generate `VoltageProfileFile_long`)*

```
sns.set()

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,4))

sns.boxplot(x='household', y='value', hue='phase', data=VoltageProfileFile_long, ax=ax)
plt.title('Boxplot of Values by Household and Phases')
plt.tight_layout()

plt.show()
plt.clf()
plt.close()
```

[image: Image Output]